# 9patch border black pixels visible

Tags: android

I need express help with 9 patch. I run **draw9patch**  and change and save as name.9.png and save at res/drawable ( later tried in res/drawable-hdpi but  didn't help) but problem is when I show on devic/emilator it doesn't strech and that black pixels at border are still visible ( I thought it is visible only inside 9patch for creating intersection ). Can somebody told me what is wrong ? I saved as name.9.png but it seems like it not recognize like 9.patch

Comment: That happened quite a few times to me since the latest SDK. Never found out why this is the case, multiple clearing of the project solves it usually though *(Eclipse `Project -> Clean...`)*. So try that. But I'm also interested why this is happening. Edit: To be clear, that happens with valid 9patches that have worked for ages, so chances are you are doing nothing wrong.

Comment: I can confirm what alextsc has just written. I had the same issue and solution :)

Comment: by saving 9.png wont work try by using the draw9patch tool to generate 9 patch image.

Comment: @PadmaKumar I generated with tools/draw9patch tool from command line and then saved on Desktop ( it has .9.png extension, I didn't manually changed)

Comment: how you are setting your 9patch image to view(is it R.drawable.name.9patch) can U attach you 9patch image.

Comment: @PadmaKumar I put in xml like android:background="drawable/name". Is that correct way ?

Comment: ya its correct only. can you check once that you have same image name in  drawable-mdpi & ldpi. whats you current screen resolution?

Comment: I've had the issue alextsc_off describes repeatedly with a library project that contains some 9patch resources. Cleaning the library project or all projects doesn't seem to completely solve the issue until i remove the library reference, clean, re-add the library reference.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure transparency is not set in the outer pixel border that sets the patches. The Draw9Patch tool accepts it so it looks correct but it never actually works in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure your 9patch image is named like this: imageName.9.png